# Python MagicMock to os.listdir not raise error

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I would like to set os.listdir to raise OSError in UT but it not raise anything.

My code:

```
def get_list_of_files(path):
    try:
        list_of_files = sorted([filename for filename in
                                os.listdir(path) if
                                filename.startswith('FILE')])

    except OSError as error:
    raise Exception(error)

    return list_of_files

def setUp(self):
    self.listdir_patcher = patch('os.listdir')
    self.mock_listdir = self.listdir_patcher.start()
    self.mock_listdir_rv = MagicMock()
    self.mock_listdir.return_value = self.mock_listdir_rv

def tearDown(self):
    self.listdir_patcher.stop()
def test(self):
    e = OSError('abc')
    self.mock_listdir_rv.side_effect = e
    with self.assertRaises(OSError):
         get_list_of_files('path')
```

What is the problem?
(I can not use normal Mock to os.listdir)

Comment: What does `get_list_of_files()` look like? How is it using `os.listdir()`, did you  import `os` or did you use `from os import listdir`?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly create a `MagicMock` instance for `self.mock_listdir.return_value`. That's the *default*.

Comment: 'get_list_of_files' use 'os.listdir' to get list and then filter it... not complicate

Comment: A simple sample function would be helpful to illustrate how you used `os.listdir()`; a common error when using mock is to patch the wrong place.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *I can not use normal Mock to os.listdir*. You are using the normal mock to `os.listdir` (the default is to use `MagicMock` everywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the side effect for `self.mock_listdir`, not it's return value:

```
def test(self):
    e = OSError('abc')
    self.mock_listdir.side_effect = e
    with self.assertRaises(OSError):
         get_list_of_files('path')
```

After all, you want the call to `os.listdir()` to raise the exception, not the call to the return value of `os.listdir()` (you never use `os.listdir()()`).

Demo (using `patch()` as a context manager, which has the same effects as using it as a decorator):

```
>>> from unittest.mock import patch
>>> import os
>>> with patch('os.listdir') as mock_listdir:
...     mock_listdir.side_effect = OSError('abc')
...     os.listdir('path')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 930, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 986, in _mock_call
    raise effect
OSError: abc
```

Note that setting the `side_effect` of the `self.mock_listdir` mock will persist to other tests! You should really use a new patch *per test*. You can use `patch` as a decorator on each test, use this instead of using a per-testcase patcher:

```
@patch('os.listdir')
def test(self, mock_listdir):
    e = OSError('abc')
    mock_listdir.side_effect = e
    with self.assertRaises(OSError):
         get_list_of_files('path')
```

If you do stick to using a patcher you start in the `setUp`, you'd have to clear the side effect afterwards (set it to `None`).

Aside from all that, there is no need to explicitly create the `MagicMock` instance for a `return_value`; that's the default return value already. You could instead store that default:

```
self.mock_listdir = self.listdir_patcher.start()
self.mock_listdir_rv = self.mock_listdir.return_value
```